# How to add multiple quantity in product detail page below size attribute magento 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento2

Please let me know how we can add multiple quantity in product detail page if it's possible than what process we have to follow to implement in **magento 2**.

[image]

```
 <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
 <div class="box-tocart">
<div class="fieldset">
    <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
    <div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="number"
                   name="qty"
                   id="qty"
                   maxlength="12"
                   value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                   title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                   />
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                class="action primary tocart"
                id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
        </button>
        <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
 <script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
     "#product_addtocart_form": {
         "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
            "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
         }
     }
  }
 </script>
 <?php else : ?>
   <script>
      require([
      'jquery',
      'mage/mage',
      'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
       'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
       ], function ($) {
       'use strict';

    $('#product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
        radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                bindSubmit: false
            });

            widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Bespoke/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml in this file we need to implemented.

this code is for single quantity which we have to do same as given above image.

Comment: You are barely giving anything here. Please update the question with more details, the code which you have tried, your expectation etc.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia i have mention the code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to add multiple configurations at the same time with different quantities from the configurable product page.

In order to do this you can create a new extension with a controller that behaves similarly to the one that you can find in the core that adds the item in a group.

The difference with that is the fact that [there](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Addgroup.php) the products are added without information, instead of that you should use [addProduct](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L352) and pass all the information needed.

If you don't want to develop this yourself you can check for extensions on the web, a quick google search made me find [something similar](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-configurable-product-grid-table-view-for-magento-2.html) to what you want to create, but since I'm not the person that developed that extension nor tried it myself I cannot tell if it is any good.